# Linear regression in a chosen range of points

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

Hi I'm absolutely newbie in Mathematica and have following problem:

My list looks like `{{50, 0.75}, {51, 0.76}, ...`, and I want to choose a range out of my x-values (I don't want so say: *from point 150 to ...*, I want to choose with values like *from x value 50 to 60*), with only these points a linear regression has to be done.

I tried with `LinearModelFit[data, x, x]`, and Mathematica made a linear regression with all values, now I want to choose a range but I can't find a solution =(

Has somebody an idea?

Comment: You can use `Select` to filter your `data`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by @b.gatessucks you can use `Select`.

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x] + RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}]}, {x, 0, 15, 0.25}];
pl = ListPlot[data];
ff = LinearModelFit[data, Sin[x], x]
Show[pl, Plot[ff[x], {x, 0, 15}]];
```

and after selection over the range [2,8]:

```
ff2 = LinearModelFit[Select[data, #[[1]] > 2 && #[[1]] < 8 &], Sin[x], x]
Show[pl, Plot[{ff[x],ff2[x]}, {x, 0, 15}]];
```

[image]

Comment: The `Select[]` looks a bit nicer if you use a compound inequality: `2 < #[[1]] < 8 &`.

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically select the desired data range by using locators:

```
data = Table[{x, x x }, {x, 0, 100}]; 
Manipulate[((p1 = Sort[p][[All, 1]]; 
             lm = LinearModelFit[Select[data, (p1[[1]] < #[[1]] < p1[[2]] &)], x, x];
             Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> 10^4 {-1, 1}], 
                      Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 100},  PlotStyle -> Red]]), 
{{p, {{1, 0}, {100, 0}}}, {1, 0}, {100, 0}, Locator}]
```

[image]