# How to do dynamic range selection for data fitting in Log plot?

Tags: dynamic, fitting, locator, logarithmic-scale

In **linear** plot, this can be achived by **Locator** like this:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24935/13580

```
data = Table[{x, x x }, {x, 0, 100}]; 
Manipulate[(p1 = Sort[p][[All, 1]]; 
         lm = LinearModelFit[Select[data, (p1[[1]] < #[[1]] < p1[[2]] &)], x, x];
         Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> 10^4 {-1, 1}], 
                  Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 100},  PlotStyle -> Red]]), 
{{p, {{1, 0}, {100, 0}}}, {1, 0}, {100, 0}, Locator}]
```

[image]

But in **logrithmic** plot, Locator seems not work, possibly because it only returns a linear coordinate in a graphic.

The following code is adapted from above. One locator is missing, and the other does not return desired coordinate.

```
data = Table[{x, x^2 + RandomInteger[10]}, {x, 1, 100}];
Manipulate[(p1 = Sort[p][[All, 1]];
  nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
    Select[data, (p1[[1]] < #[[1]] < p1[[2]] &)], a x^b, {a, b}, x];
  Show[ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> 10^4 {0.00001, 1},PlotLabel -> {nlm[x], p}], 
   LogLogPlot[nlm[x], {x, 0.1, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red]]), 
 {{p, {{1., 1.}, {100., 1.}}}, {1.,1.}, {100., 1.}, Locator}]
```

One alternative is to take log of the data, then use linear fitting. But I hope there is a direct way without this extra step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log Plots coordinates are confusing even built in things: [Asymmetric X and Y error bars on ListLogPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42144/5478)

`Locators` positions `p` (exact graphics coordinates) are referring to actual coordinates (those indicated by Axes) like: `Exp @ p`.

So if one want to plot a point on position `{10,10^4}` then `Log @ {10,10^4}` has to be provided.

```
data = Table[{x, x^2 + RandomInteger[10]}, {x, 1, 100}];
DynamicModule[{
  p = Log@{{1, 10}, {10, 10}}
  },
 LocatorPane[Dynamic@p, (

   Show[
    ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> 10^4 {0.00001, 1}, 
     ImageSize -> 500],
    Graphics[{
      Dynamic@Line[{{#, Log[1]}, {#, Log[10.^4]}} & /@ p[[All, 1]]],
      Dynamic[
       ControlActive[{},
        p1 = Sort[p][[All, 1]];
        nlm = 
         NonlinearModelFit[
          Select[data, (Exp@p1[[1]] < #[[1]] < Exp@p1[[2]] &)], 
          a x^b, {a, b}, x];
        First@LogLogPlot[nlm[x], {x, 0.1, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red]
        ]
       ]
      }]
    ])
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Table[{x, x^2 + RandomInteger[10]}, {x, 1, 100}];
Manipulate[(p1 = Sort[p][[All, 1]];
  nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Select[data, (E^p1[[1]] < #[[1]] < E^p1[[2]] &)], a x^b, {a, b}, x];
  Show[ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotLabel -> {nlm[x], E^p}],
       LogLogPlot[nlm[x], {x, 0.1, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red]]),
 {{p, {{0., 0.}, {Log@100., 0.}}},
       {0., 0}, {Log@100., 0.}, Locator}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]